# fft amplitude of chirp in python

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, dft

I HAVE seen similar questions beeing asked but I just can't seem to get this right. Hope you guess can help if I am misunderstanding something conceptually or code-wise. 
Basically I am making a chirp from 1khz to 10khz of duration 1s with 48khz fs. 
I simply want to plot the frequency spetrum/fft of this chirp with the right amplitude. The code is:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft

N = 48000
fs = 48000.0
sine_list_x = []
K = (10000.0 - 1000.0)/(48000.0)
for x in range(N):
    sine_list_x.append(sin(2*pi*(1000.0*(x/48000.0)+(K/2.0)*(x**2)/(48000.0))))

xf = np.linspace(0.0, fs/2.0, N/2)
yf = fft(sine_list_x)
yf = yf / sqrt(N)
#yf = yf / N

fig3 = pl.figure()
ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(111)
ax3.plot(xf, abs(yf[0:N/2]))
```

The plot from the above code i shown here
[image]

I know that the fft function does not normalize but I kind of get conflicting info from similar questions which say so normalize by sqrt(N), N and other things..

What I expected to see in the plot if I had normalized correctly was an amplitude of 1 in the since that is the amplitude of the chirp. Is that a wrong assumption? Or do I simply do something wrong in the normalization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the time-domain and for a sweep with slowly varying frequency, the sum of squared samples of an integer number of cycles (or of a sufficiently large number of cycles) can be approximated by

```
     0.5*N*At*At
```

where `N` is the number of samples, and `At` is the sweep's amplitude.
For your given parameters (`N=48000`, `At=1`), this would be 24000 which comes pretty close to the exact value of ~23999.9986331 provided in [@tom10's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29402860/2994596).

On the other hand in the frequency-domain (looking at the graph of the frequency spectrum), the complete spectrum can be approximated by 2 boxes (as could be expected by a linear frequency sweep):

- one from 1000 to 10000 which you show on your graph
- and another from 38000 to 47000 which arises out of the Hermitian symmetry of the frequency spectrum of real signals.

The sum of the squared (frequency-domain) samples in this case could then be approximated by

```
     ((10000-1000)+(47000-38000))*Af*Af == 18000*Af*Af
```

Now [Parseval's theorem for the disrete Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem) states that:

[image: \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left|x[n]\right|^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left|X[k]\right|^2]

which after accounting for the `1/sqrt(N)` normalization and substituting the approximate values found above yields:

```
     24000 = 18000*Af*Af
```

Thus `Af` should be approximately equal to `sqrt(24000/18000) = 1.1547...`, which is consistent with the graph you plotted.

Comment: `2*((10000-1000)+(47000-38000))*Af*Af` is not equal to `18000*Af*Af` ...

Answer (score 2):

What you expect to be conserved between the pair is the total power, which it is.  So if, after normalizing by `sqrt(N)`, you do:

```
print sum(abs(yf*yf)), sum(np.array(sine_list_x)**2)
```

you get

```
23999.9986331 23999.9986331
```

which is at is should be.

Since you're not looking at a pure sine wave it would be difficult to compare the amplitudes, but the power should always work.